# Database Design: Storing user information from different sites Edit: EAV (entity attribute value)

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to design a database that would house information about a user from different websites. Basically an aggregation of user information so that user wouldn't have to log into different websites and get similar information in one place. Sort of like mint.com The problem is that most of these different websites contain different subsets of data. For example one site would demand about 47 columns while another would demand only about 13. Now the logical thing in my mind would be to break each website into it's own table. Yet  one table with 47 columns seemed cumbersome and any attempt i made to break it down into smaller tables just made it seem more insane. A friend of mine suggested that if there were similarities between the fields from the websites that I could have only three tables. Like so:

[image: visio_design]

The example above basically takes anything that would have been a column name if i made it a table per website schema and It places that column name into the 'field_name' column as an entry. Since changes to the users information at each site only happens once a day(in the early morning) the composite key would stay unique based on the day. Instead of all the values for a website in one row each in its own table they are basically all segmented and now getting the data involves slightly longer queries with everything basically being done in the WHERE clause.

This would be really good if say I could use all 13 from one website and combine it with 13 from the website with 47 columns and only have to worry about 34 columns and map the data to the proper site using the mapping table. Yet I've analyzed the data and there is no way to do it this.. Each site would have to use ALL the fields since they are not similar enough to combine. Which would mean each day the data table in the example above would generate about 120 rows. I really like the concept...if any of my requirements change I wouldn't have to edit the schema just in my code add another value to the field_name. Which seems to be the only main advantage over the other way.

Would it make more sense to break each website into its own table and have 4 tables generate only 4 rows a day DESPITE one table having 47 or would it make more sense doing something like the example above for more Scalabilitys..?

Comment: This is called EAV (entity attribute value) model and it really should be avoided for most scenarios.  It doesn't scale well at all, makes referential integrity pretty much impossible to maintain, and adds a lot of (normally) unnecessary complexity to a design.

Comment: If you are adding 4 rows a day you don't need to be concerned with scalability.  Break down the data in 3rd normal form.  Start with the data that is common to all.   For data that is specific to a site I would use a convention where where start the table with the site name.  Let the web site determine the name displayed to the user.

Comment: Any chance that the data managed by the websites might change over time? How do you plan to handle that?

Comment: The data is mostly financial data....so i don't see the fields themselves changing to much. In the example above if lets say one of the websites added or removed field it wouldn't be a problem because its a row. So I could easier add that in with a bit of code and just add a new 'field_name'. The normal table by site way I was thinking I would have to add it or remove columns in the actual schema based on need. I don't see that as THAT much of an issue. It might get weird if someone tries to pull in data that doesn't have the extra field.